# Simple approach to Access SOAP Web services from MVC3 applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, soap, restsharp

I need a simple approach to access a 3rd party SOAP Webservice from a MVC3/C# web application. I had hoped to use RestSharp, but I think this will only deal with RESTful Webservices.

The information I have on their API is currently:

"SOAP & JSON based APIs", and their examples are PHP/SOAP examples.

Comment: I'm very new to WCF, but can't you simply add a WebReference to the wsdl which would create the proxy classes that you can then call from a controller?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am wondering whether WCF is a little over the top from what I have read. Is it still the standard MS recommended approach? I have also come across ServiceStack which looks good for both protocols.

Comment: Just discovered that I can use REST/JSON. So no problem any longer. Thanks